# Real Starting Address Of A Process in Memory / Win32 Debug APIs

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, entry-point

At first, I'm a newbie on c++ and debuging. I use CreateProcess api with DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS parameter, then wait for CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT. When recived, i check for the Eip register to get the address of the point. And i tought that this point is the Main function's address.

To verify this idea i used ollydbg to see the starting address of the exe. But it wasn't same with mine. The one i found with debug apis is 0x77a364d8, but olly says that it's 0x00401000. Then i didn't stop and checked for the address 0x77a364d8 in olly. I found the address and set a breakpoint there.

Then I reloaded the olly and saw that olly firstly goes 0x77a364d8 address and loades the process and then goes to the 0x00401000 address and waits there. 0x77a364d8 address points some ntdll functions to load process to memory as i see.

If it's true, how can i get the 0x00401000 address by code( c++, i'm a newbie and please cross the t's :) ), and is it the Main function's address or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you receive the [`CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679302%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you should be able to access the [`CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) member of the union. It has a member called `lpStartAddress`.

Your debugging event loop should look something like:

```
DWORD dwContinueDebugStatus = DBG_CONTINUE;
while(dwContinueDebugStatus)
{
    DEBUG_EVENT debugEvt;
    WaitForDebugEvent(&debugEvt, INFINITE);
    switch(debugEvt.dwDebugEventCode)
    {
    case CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
        // Grab the main thread entry point.
        LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE exentry = debugEvt.u.CreateProcessInfo.lpStartAddress;
        break;
        /* Handle the rest of your debug events here. */
    }
    ContinueDebugEvent(debugEvt.dwProcessId, debugEvt.dwThreadId, dwContinueDebugStatus);
}
```

**Edit:**
A couple things I forgot to mention...

Getting the entry point by any of these means will likely be the CRT function that calls your `main()`. There isn't a reliable way to get the `main()` without symbol lookups in using `dbghelp.dll`.

Also, the book [*Debugging Applications*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735608865) by John Robbins has a chapter about creating a small debugger with some example code. It is probably the best documentation/example I've found (but I wish it were better). It can be had pretty cheap so it might be worth looking at.

Comment: This is way simpler than my solution!

Comment: That was actually what i'm looking for. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The entry point will *not* (at least normally) be the same as `main`. The signature for the entry point is `void entrypoint(void);`. That has to retrieve the command line, parse it into individual arguments, etc., in preparation for calling `main` (and there's an entirely separate one that retrieves the rather different "stuff" necessary before calling `WinMain` in a GUI program).

If you want the actual address of `main`, you might want to at least try using [`SymFromName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681325.aspx) for the names `_main` and/or `_wmain` (or, if you might be dealing with a GUI program, `WinMain`/`wWinmain`) to get to code that's really part of the target program instead of something from a library module almost nobody has ever even seen.

Comment: Thanks for the informations. Seans's answer suits me for now, but i should keep these in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is all from memory, so it might contain a few mistakes.

In order to find the entry point address of the EXE in a new process, you need to read this process's PEB field `ImageBaseAddress`. The PEB is always at a fixed address, but it depends on if your EXE is 32 or 64-bit, which you'll have to determine beforehand (there is a 32-bit PEB for WOW64 but I think it may not be initialized yet at that point).

Note that you can't just fetch this from the EXE because it might be relocated due to ASLR. Once you have this, you can read PE header of the EXE using `ReadProcessMemory` and get the `AddressOfEntryPoint` field from the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` struct. It's an RVA so add it to the base address found earlier, and voila, you have your entry point address.